# Umbraco, using templates in multiple pages

Tags: asp.net, templates, umbraco

Im trying to use a template in two different templates, i want just one place to edit the content in the template 'test', but im not able to do that, i can't figure out how to include the template on both 'forhandlere' and 'forside' without the 'test' template being a child template of both, i dont want that, then there are 2 places i need to edit the same content.

How do i include the 'test' template in multiple templates?

[image: templates]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I totally get what you want to do so please correct me if I'm wrong:

You wan't to include the content of the templete called "test" in the templates "forside/forside_content" and "forhandlere/forhandlere_content"?

Instead of creating a templete for "test" maybe you should create it as a Partial View and in your other templates use `@Html.Partial("test")` to include it.